# Задержка у бота

Tags: telegram, бот, telethon

Сделал бота для Телеграм, который отправляет gif на определённые слова в сообщениях чата. Если он отвечает не гифкой, а сообщением - всё происходит моментально, в случае с gif - задержка в несколько секунд (в зависимости от размера самой гифки, но они и так сжатые сильно). Что можно сделать?

```
import telethon
import glob

def generate_path():
    path = "Bot/gif/"
    num_files = sum(os.path.isfile(f) for f in glob.glob(path + "*"))
    a = random.randint(1, num_files)
    return path + str(a) + ".gif"

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(func=lambda event: event.is_group))
async def new_message(event: Message):
    if "gif" == event.raw_text.lower():
        await bot.send_message(event.chat.id, file=open(generate_path(), 'rb'))
```

Comment: Укажите в тегах и в описании вопроса библиотеку, которую вы используете

Comment: Загрузить гиф на сервера телеграма в виде файлового вложения и пересылать это вложение по необходимости

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, можно поподробнее про сервер и вложения? Просто создать чат с ботом, закинуть туда гифки и оттуда пересылать?

Comment: Да, по сути именно так ;)